# How to resolve bound object from bindingexpression with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Hi does anyone know if there are any inbuilt classes for resolving a bound object from a bindingexpression and it's DataItem and property path?

I'm attempting to write a Blend 3 behavior for textboxes which automatically invokes methods on an object bound to the textbox Text property.

The textbox is bound to a property on a viewmodel class.  What I want to do is resolve the viewmodel class from the binding expression and then make calls on this.

I first retrieve the binding expression from the behavior's associated object like so:

```
private BindingExpression GetTextBinding()
{
    return this.AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
}
```

Having done this, if we look at the binding expression, we can see it has a reference to the data context via the binding expression's DataItem property.

In addition, we have the relative path of the property which is bound on the binding expression's parent binding.

So, we can get this information:

```
var bindingExpression = GetTextBinding();
object dataContextItem = bindingExpression.DataItem;
PropertyPath relativePropertyPath = bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path;
```

Now, this property path could potentially be a deeply nested and complex path, which I would very much like to avoid having to (re?)implement resolution of.  I've searched around the .NET documentation and bounced around the assemblies with reflector, all to no avail - I can't find what surely must exist - there's got to be some class which performs the resolution of the path for the dataitem (the data context).

Does anyone know where this might exist?  Any suggestions for alternative ways of resolving the bound object?

Note, I'm trying to get at the bound object which is the *parent* of the bound property (the string in this case) - I can obviously easily get at the bound value, but it's the parent I need.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Phil

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Below is a quick implementation for an extension method that will do just what you are looking for.  I couldn't find anything related to this either.  The method below will always return null if for some reason the value cannot be found.  The method won't work when the path includes [].  I hope this helps!

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this BindingExpression expression, object dataItem)            
{
    if (expression == null || dataItem == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    string bindingPath = expression.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
    string[] properties = bindingPath.Split('.');

    object currentObject = dataItem;
    Type currentType = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        currentType = currentObject.GetType();                
        PropertyInfo property = currentType.GetProperty(properties[i]);
        if (property == null)
        {                    
            currentObject = null;
            break;
        }
        currentObject = property.GetValue(currentObject, null);
        if (currentObject == null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return (T)currentObject;
}
```

Comment: My2cents, Is there a reason your passing in the object dataItem? Why not just change the method signature to take one param instead of two and get the dataItem from the BindingExpression?

Comment: This doesn't look like it will resolve property paths with indexers, or does it?

Comment: the futre proof way stands below

Answer (score 33):

For people in the future who stumble on this question:

When .NET 4.5 becomes available it will have a number of new properties on the BindingExpression to greatly simplify what you are looking for.

**ResolvedSource** - The object that is actually being bound to, helpful when you have a binding source like 'grandparent.parent.me.Name'.  This would return the 'me' object.

**ResolvedSourcePropertyName** - The name of the property on the ResolvedSource that is bound to.  In the case above, "Name".

Similarly, there will be **Target**, and **TargetName** properties.

With these helper properties on BindingExpression you could use some shorter and much more simplified reflection that is more likely to work in extreme situations (indexers).

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to force the binding expression to update these properties? I am in a peculiar situation where I am cloning a binding when a controls data context changes and getting the source from the binding expression, however these properties seem to remain null until after both the property changed and data context changed events.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor I can interpret you question multiple ways. I'd recommend starting up a new question instead of adding on here.

Answer (score 11):

Just for further information, PropertyPath resolution is handled by an internal MS class called PropertyPathWorker, which lives in PresentationFramework under MS.Internal.Data.  If you open it up in Reflector, you can see it's quite complicated, so I wouldn't recommend trying to duplicate its functionality.  It's tightly coupled with the overall Binding architecture.

The most robust way  to support all property path syntax--including attached dependency properties and hierarchical traversal--is probably to create a dummy DependencyObject with a DependencyProperty.  You can then create a Binding from your 'owner' path to the dummy dependency property, create a new BindingExpression and then call the expression's UpdateTarget.  It's a rather heavy way of accomplishing what, on the surface, looks like a simple task, but I think there are a lot of hidden gotchas in the way property paths are resolved for binding.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this other StackOverflow [solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577802/wpf-getting-a-property-value-from-a-binding-path) may also work for you.

Copied code block for reference, read original post for more details provided by Thomas Levesque.

```
public static class PropertyPathHelper
{
    public static object GetValue(object obj, string propertyPath)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(propertyPath);
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;
        binding.Source = obj;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(_dummy, Dummy.ValueProperty, binding);
        return _dummy.GetValue(Dummy.ValueProperty);
    }

    private static readonly Dummy _dummy = new Dummy();

    private class Dummy : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(Dummy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Dan Bryant already noted, `PropertyPath` resolution is tightly coupled with the overall binding architecture.
If you need the exact same resolution as WPF does it, you should probably use Thomas Levesque's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579263/3107430) question.

However, if you just need general path resolution, you can use a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pather.CSharp) [Pather.CSharp](https://github.com/Domysee/Pather.CSharp) I developed that does exactly that.

It is essentially similar to zhech's answer, but more sophisticated.

Its main method is `Resolve` on the `Resolver` class. Passing in the **target object** and a **path** as string returns the desired result.
An **Example:**

```
IResolver resolver = new Resolver(); 
var target = new { Property1 = new { Property2 = "value" } };   
object result = r.Resolve(target, "Property1.Property2");
```

It also supports **collection access** via index or **dictionary access** via key.
Example paths for these are:

```
"ArrayProperty[5]"
"DictionaryProperty[Key]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case others find it useful, below is a quick one liner extension method for .net4.5 (and beyond) to retrieve the bound value.

```
public static object? GetValue(this BindingExpression bindingExpression)
{
    return 
      bindingExpression?.ResolvedSource.GetType().GetProperty(
        bindingExpression.ResolvedSourcePropertyName)?.GetValue(
           bindingExpression.ResolvedSource);
}
```