# How to get value from Binding object in Code as a string (WPF)

Tags: wpf, string, data-binding, multibinding, valueconverter

I'd like to get value from Binding in my code and use it as a string. How Can I do that?

```
Binding b = new Binding("MyProperty")
                {
                    Source = myobject
                };
//[...]
string value = b //HOW TO GET VALUE FROM b ?
```

**BTW:**
I would like the Converter attached to Binding to be called when retrieving this value.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question well, but my goal is only to get value as it is Binded by "b"

Comment: What if i have  <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} - {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="Id"/>
                        </MultiBinding> and I want to get string result = //Smith - 777 There must be an option to get Binding / Multibinding to extract what binds it to, right?

Comment: If you're trying to use the binding to get the value of `myobject.MyPoperty`, [have a look at these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577802/wpf-getting-a-property-value-from-a-binding-path). This question would be much improved if you would state, clearly and unambiguously, in English, what value you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution could be an auxiliary class with DependencyProperty.

**Auxiliary class**

```
public class TestClass : FrameworkElement
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(TestClass), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

**Binding conversion to String**

```
Binding b = new Binding("MyProperty") { Source = myobject };
TestClass tc = new TestClass { DataContext = b };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tc, TestClass.MyPropertyProperty, b);
string txt = tc.MyProperty;
```

**Advantages:**

- You can use Binding and MultiBinding
- You can use Converters

**Disadvantages:**

- Each time we create a class that inherits from the [FrameworkElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx), which means that we do unnecessary operations.