# Get source property type from BindingExpression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0

I am trying to find out the source property type of a binding expression. I want to do this because I want to use the [UpdateSourceExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourceexceptionfilter.aspx) to provide a more useful error message than just the generic “couldn’t convert”.

In .NET 4.5 I use [ResolvedSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.resolvedsource.aspx) and [ResolvedSourcePropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.resolvedsourcepropertyname.aspx) with reflection to get the source property type like this:

```
PropertyInfo sourceProperty = expr.ResolvedSource.GetType().GetProperty(expr.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
Type propertyType = sourceProperty.PropertyType;
```

This works just fine. However both those BindingExpression properties were just introduced with .NET 4.5, and I’m still on 4.0 (can’t really update because of Windows XP).

So is there a nice way to do this in .NET 4.0? I thought about getting the internal `SourceItem` and `SourcePropertyName` properties using reflection or just the private `Worker` to get those values but I would rather avoid to access internal/private properties or fields (and I think this would also require me to do something about trust? What implications are there?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not too pretty, but without access to private methods:

```
string[] splits = expr.ParentBinding.Path.Path.Split('.');
Type type = expr.DataItem.GetType();
foreach (string split in splits) {
    type = type.GetProperty(split).PropertyType;
}
```

Thus, we are able to resolve the source property.

Comment: I guess that would be an acceptable solution if I can assume that all paths are just simple paths like that (they are right now). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i use this in my code to find source property Type

```
        BindingExpression bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, SelectedItemProperty);
        object s = bindingExpression?.ResolvedSource;
        string pn = bindingExpression?.ResolvedSourcePropertyName;

        var type = s?.GetType().GetProperty(pn)?.PropertyType;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549785/how-to-resolve-bound-object-from-bindingexpression-with-wpf) is one solution that is independent from internal/private .NET objects.

Property `expr.ResolvedSource` is `null` when `DataContext` is used from parent control, so it will not be useful.

What is the reason to finding source type?

Why do not use simple `String.Format("Binding has exception in path {0}", expr.ParentBinding.Path.Path?? String.Empty)`?

Comment: I’m not interested in the binding target (the component) but the binding source. And I know neither the binding target nor the property that the binding is applied to—but I’m not interested in it either; I get the BindingExpression from the [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourceexceptionfiltercallback.aspx). Btw. your code could be just simplified to `TextBox.TextProperty.PropertyType`.