# WPF TextBox validation issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have textbox those name are checkDescriptionTxtBox and parameterTxtBox. Both are using same validation rule such are available in TextBoxValidator.cs. But the one difference is ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" added in parameterTxtBox. checkDescriptionTxtBox validation working as expected but Why parameterTxtBox validation not working?Could you please help anyone.

i want to validate the value after source property has been updated. I have debugged the Validate method. During checkDescriptionTxtBox validation parameter value passing as string but when parameterTxtBox validation parameter value not passing as string instead difference binding value. So i want to validate the value after the source property has been updated. How to achieve this?

```
<TextBox Name="checkDescriptionTxtBox" Width="700" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}">
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="CheckDescription" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                            <v:TextBoxValidator></v:TextBoxValidator>
                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    </Binding>
                                </TextBox.Text>
                            </TextBox>

<TextBox Name="parameterTxtBox" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="200" Height="20" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}">
                                                <TextBox.Text>
                                                    <Binding Path="ParameterValue" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                                                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                                            <v:TextBoxValidator ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"></v:TextBoxValidator>
                                                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                                    </Binding>
                                                </TextBox.Text>
                                            </TextBox>


    TextBoxValidator.cs    
        public class TextBoxValidator : ValidationRule
            {
             public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString().Trim()))
                            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty");

                        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i want to validate the value after source property has been updated. I have debugged the Validate method. During  checkDescriptionTxtBox validation parameter value passing as string but when parameterTxtBox validation parameter value not passing as string instead difference binding value. So i want to validate the value after the source property has been updated. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `ValidationStep` property to `UpdatedValue` means that the validation rule will be run *after* the source property has been updated. If the source property isn't updated, the validation rule won't run. The default value of the `ValidationStep` property is `RawProposedValue` which means that the validation rule is run *before* the value conversion occurs.

So since the `checkDescriptionTxtBox` works, you should simply remove `ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"` form the `TextBoxValidator` of `parameterTxtBox`.

> But i want to validate the value after source property has been updated. I have debugged the Validate method. During checkDescriptionTxtBox validation parameter value passing as string but when parameterTxtBox validation parameter value not passing as string instead difference binding value. So i want to validate the value after the source property has been updated. How to achieve this?

Cast the `value` to `BindingExpression` a use some reflection:

```
public class TextBoxValidator : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string s = null;
        BindingExpression be = value as BindingExpression;
        if(be != null)
        {
            object sourceObject = be.ResolvedSource;
            string sourceProperty = be.ResolvedSourcePropertyName;
            if(sourceObject != null && sourceProperty != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperty(sourceProperty);
                s = pi.GetValue(sourceObject) as string;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            s = value as string;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty");

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

> Currently i am using .Net 4 . I hope be.ResolvedSource; and be.ResolvedSourcePropertyName supported in .Net 4.5. Then how can i achieve this in .Net 4?

This should work in .NET Framework 4:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    string s = null;
    BindingExpression be = value as BindingExpression;
    if (be != null)
    {
        object sourceObject = be.DataItem;
        string sourceProperty = be.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
        if (sourceObject != null && sourceProperty != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperty(sourceProperty);
            s = pi.GetValue(sourceObject) as string;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        s = value as string;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return new ValidationResult(false, "Value cannot be empty");

    return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. But i want to validate the value after source property has been updated. I have debugged the Validate method. During  checkDescriptionTxtBox validation parameter value passing as string but when parameterTxtBox validation parameter value not passing as string instead difference binding value. So i want to validate the value after the source property has been updated. How to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently i am using .Net 4 . I hope be.ResolvedSource; and be.ResolvedSourcePropertyName supported in .Net 4.5. Then how can i achieve this in .Net 4?

Comment: @Arunagiri: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671689/get-source-property-type-from-bindingexpression.

Comment: string[] splits = expr.ParentBinding.Path.Path.Split('.');
Type type = expr.DataItem.GetType();
foreach (string split in splits) {
    type = type.GetProperty(split).PropertyType;
}

Comment: how to use the above code in my Validate method. Could you please share full code of the validate method?