# How to resolve a binding expression set on a custom Dependancy Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made a custom Searchable ComboBox, with a Filter defined on the default CollectionView

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource)
view.Filter += FilterPredicate;
```

The filter predicate of the ComboBox :

```
private bool FilterPredicate(object value)
{
    return PropertyPathHelper.GetValue(value, FilterPropertyPath).ToString().Contains(PART_FilterTextBox.Text);
}
//value is instance of current filtered item: Student{ FullName="SunnyXyz" , Age=30 }
//& FilterPropertyPath="FullName"
```

**FilterPropertyPath** is a "string" DependancyProperty, that acts similar to DisplayMemberPath, to locate the text property on which to apply the filtering in the bound item. PropertyPathHelper.GetValue creates a dummy binding & resolves the bind path, but this method is slow/inelegant/doesn't seem like the right approach. (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7041604/852318)

***Can anyone help with an alternative right way or a more elegant way to pass the FilterPropertyPath information***

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you can use reflection to get the property value dynamically from a string.

`value.GetType().GetProperty(FilterPropertyPath).GetValue(value)`

Note that GetProperty returns null if the property with the given name is not found.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi, Two concerns regarding this approach, 1. reflection is terribly slow, 2. I need this to work with nested path? like Class A { Class B { Class C { string GetMe { get; set; } } } }, 
then value.GetType().GetProperty("A.B.C.GetMe").GetValue(value)

Comment: You sir are right. Haven't thought about nested paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) in order to achive your target.

You can use an helper class for building and then executing an expression which gives you the value of your PropertyPath. Here the code:

```
public static class PropertyPathHelper
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(object instance, string propPath)
    {
        Delegate runtimeDelegate;

        System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression instanceParameter =
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(instance.GetType(), "p");

        string[] properties = propPath.Split('.');

        System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression currentExpression =
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(instanceParameter, properties[0]);

        System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression lambdaExpression =
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(currentExpression, instanceParameter);

        for (int i = 1; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            currentExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(lambdaExpression.Body, properties[i]);
            lambdaExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(currentExpression, instanceParameter);
        }

        runtimeDelegate = lambdaExpression.Compile();

        return (T)runtimeDelegate.DynamicInvoke(instance);
    }
}
```

Of course you can improve that method by using a static dictionary which stores the compiled lambda expressions. Expressions are *faster* than using reflection.
You can use this method in this way:

```
One one = new One() { Two = new Two() { Three = new Three() { Description = "StackOverflow" } } };
string result = PropertyPathHelper.GetValue<string>(one, "Two.Three.Description");
```

The "result" string will be set to "StackOverflow". Therefore your filter predicate will become:

```
private bool FilterPredicate(object value)
{
    return PropertyPathHelper.GetValue<string>(value, FilterPropertyPath).Contains(PART_FilterTextBox.Text);
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Using lambda expressions instead of reflections seems like a really smart move ( will try to benchmark & update speed comparison )

Comment: @II Vic, the code was excellent, didn't have to run any synthetic benchmark, had a dummy application where a specific user control's binding expressions were being resolved by creating a new dummy binding; Replacing that code with your Expression Trees approach improved performance to a significant noticeable extend (tried several times, where the only change was this method).