# How to clear WPF PasswordBox bound to ViewModel via Behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, behavior

I write WPF MVVM Prism 6.2 application. In the view of login window (that is PrismUserControl) I have a PaswordBox bound (via Behavior) to 'Password' property in view model. **PasswordBox must be empty each time the login window is called while the application is running.** *(For example after the user closed current session he or she must see only empty Shell and login window above the Shell.)* My problem is that the abovementioned PasswordBox is displayed empty only first time after application loading. If the PaswordBox is displayed in second or third time e.t.c, then it is not empty. Please see the picture below:

[image]

As you can see Password is not empty but it must be empty in this case. Below is XAML snippet from login window markup where the PaswordBox is:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . . .
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
. . . . . . . . . . . . . .
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="30" Margin="0 10 5 0" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="UserPasswordBox">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behavior:PasswordBoxBindingBehavior Password="{Binding Password}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Below is the class of the behavior which is also involved in XAML as you can se above:

```
public class PasswordBoxBindingBehavior : Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += OnPasswordBoxValueChanged;
    }

    public SecureString Password
    {
        get { return (SecureString)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Password", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordBoxBindingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private void OnPasswordBoxValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, PasswordProperty);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = binding.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
            if (property != null)
                property.SetValue(binding.DataItem, AssociatedObject.SecurePassword, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And below is 'Password' property that is in the view model. The PasswordBox is bound to this property via PasswordBoxBindingBehavior:

```
public SecureString Password
{
    get { return this._password; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._password, value); }
}
```

I need that the PasswordBox be empty each time when login window is displayed during the application working. I've tryed to clear programmatically 'Password' property in the view model but it doesn't help. How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 7):

You could hook up a `PropertyChangedCallback` for the `Password` dependency property of your behaviour that sets the `Password` property of the `PasswordBox` to an empty string when the `Password` source property of the view model is set to `null`:

```
public class PasswordBoxBindingBehavior : Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += OnPasswordBoxValueChanged;
    }

    public SecureString Password
    {
        get { return (SecureString)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Password", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordBoxBindingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSourcePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewValue == null)
        {
            PasswordBoxBindingBehavior behavior = d as PasswordBoxBindingBehavior;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= OnPasswordBoxValueChanged;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.Password = string.Empty;
            behavior.AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += OnPasswordBoxValueChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnPasswordBoxValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox passwordBox = sender as PasswordBox;
        var behavior = Interaction.GetBehaviors(passwordBox).OfType<PasswordBoxBindingBehavior>().FirstOrDefault();
        if(behavior != null)
        {
            var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(behavior, PasswordProperty);
            if (binding != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo property = binding.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
                if (property != null)
                    property.SetValue(binding.DataItem, passwordBox.SecurePassword, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can clear the `PasswordBox` by simply setting the `Password` source property to null in your view model.

Comment: mm8, thank you very much for your help. Now Password is clear every time the login window is displayed.

Comment: this is very clever, allows me to use PasswordBox in MVVM, thank you for the idea & code

Comment: Hello. This is a great answer but it does not work for bindings written like: Password="{Binding Path=(local:MyViewModel.Password)}. In this case, "binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path" value is "(0)" so the property is null. But the answer from Kevin Kalitowski works for framework 4.5 and superior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9603656/4049478. It replace the "binding.ParentBinding. ..." with "binding.ResolvedSourcePropertyName".

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach. This clears the passwordBox textbox each time the screen (the Grid within which the PasswordBox element resides) closes.

```
<Grid  Grid.LostFocus="event_method" ...

<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" ...
```

In the code behind:

```
public event_method()
{
    passwordBox.Clear();
}
```